# How can I store a custom object in UserDefaults?

Tags: local-storage, userdefaults, custom-object

I have a struct called Note with some basic properties like `id, title, body`. But i also have a property `location` of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. I want to provide local storage with UserDefaults. Because `CLLocationCoordinate2D` does not conform to the Codable Protocol I used the automatic help from Xcode that created an extension with two protocol stubs. It looks like that:

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        <#code#>
    }
    
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        <#code#>
    }
}

struct Note: Codable {
    let id: UUID
    let title: String
    let body: String
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

and this is the point where i need help. Because i don't know how to fill the gaps marked with `<#code#>`. Maybe someone could give a hint. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution here [developer.apple.com/](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable {

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case latitude
    case longitude
  }

  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      self.init()
    
      let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      latitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
      longitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
   }

  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
      try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
      try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
  }
}
```